# reCAPTCHA with images not working as it should

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Sometimes when I'm quick, I get a reCAPTCHA to verify that I am human. I'm totally fine with this. Today I got a reCAPTCHA with images. I had to select peanuts or street signs, and somehow I am not able to get past that reCAPTCHA. Either it is not working, or I am dumb enough but that really sucks. I had to beat reCAPTCHA by pressing the back button, wait a bit and resubmit my post.

Is it me or is the image verification method for reCAPTCHA broken?

Comment: I had a joyous time with that thing too. Really if you dont know sherbet from ice cream :-) then don't tell me I selected the wrong thing :-)  There were times when i had to do 5 sets because I screwed up so much. From what i can tell so far, there are 2-3 images you must get correct, and they are subjective selections, like breaded meat was not a bread item? Yes it SUCKS , doing it enough times you get good enough at it that you could probably program a bot to do it easily :-p  More often than not you also have to get More than One Set correct, not just one, so that adds to the fun.

Comment: Last one I had was "find the aeroplanes". That was easy ;)

Comment: Hmm, I see. Where can we vote to get it replaced? XD This is not a way to counter a bot, but this appears to be a way to counter being productive. (this is not meant as an insult btw. I mean that if I am in a flow to answer questions and reCAPTCHA stops this flow enough times, I loose motivation to continue and switch to different work)

Comment: Since this would be site wide, should this not go on MSE instead?

Comment: @CanadianLuke I wasn't sure, but you're probably right.

Comment: @LPChip make a [tag:feature-request] on [metase] and see how that goes. The comments from the others make this a [tag:status-norepro]

Comment: @m0sa how does that work? Can I just create a new question and tag it #feature-request?

Comment: @LPChip yes, like you said